# UIView declared from AppDelegate disappears when revisiting UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a declared UIView(which is for popup purposes) from AppDelegate.h. And it has been initialized on AppDelegate.m

From AppDelegate.m

```
- (UIView *)popupView
{
    if (!_popupView) {
        _popupView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _popupView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
        _popupView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return _popupView;
}
```

I am adding it to my UIViewController template as:

```
UIWindow* currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[currentWindow addSubview:_appDelegate.popupView];
```

This works fine the first time you navigate the app through tabbars. It will disappear if you go back to previously opened tabbar.

Comment: Why do you need to put the view in the app delegate? Why not create some kind of singleton class that will return the view whenever you need it?

Comment: sometimes I wish we could down vote comments.